# React JS: Unexpected use of 'event' no-restricted-globals

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-dom

I am passing the nameChangedHandler method as a reference to changed property and ultimately to the person component which i have not mentioned here, but i am getting an error in the event object.

```
class App extends Component {

  state = {
   persons: [
    {id: 'abc', name: "Max", age: 28},
    {id:'def', name: "Suzi", age: 30},
    {id:'fgh', name: "Alex", age:33}
    ],
  otherState: 'some other value',
  showPersons: false
       }

nameChangeHandler = (event) => {

  this.setState({
    persons: [
    {name: "Max", age: 28},
    {name: event.target.value, age: 30},
    {name: "Alex", age:26}
  ]
}
  );

}

 display_persons = (
  <div>
      return <Person         
             changed={()=>this.nameChangeHandler(event)}  />
    
</div>  
 );
}

return(
<div className="App">
  {display_persons}
</div>

 );

 }
 }


export default App;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you don't define `event` it thinks `event` is a global.
`onChange` provides `event` as a parameter but you have to define it.

Try this code:

```
<Person changed={(event)=>this.nameChangeHandler(event)} />
```

Or this one:

```
<Person changed={this.nameChangeHandler} />
```

*Answer to comment:*

Well its the same like `() => 2 + someParameter`. This won't work because in that arrow function `someParameter` is not known, it will give errors. the component `Person` has a property `onChange` which will propably expect just a function and passes one parameter to it which is the event of the onChange. if you pass a parameterless arrow function, like in your question, `event` will have no binding locally so it will ook for globals. like `console` from `console.log` is a global. So even this code will work:

```
(randomName) => this.nameChangeHandler(randomName)
```

bacause the `event` is bound to the parameter `randomName`.

I don't know your experience so if you have trouble understanding it maybe do some further research on 'scopes', 'parameter binding' or 'React onChange'.nMaybe these will be more clear than what i wrote :)

Comment: It worked fine, but i am still unable to grab the concept as why we had to pass the event object in arrow function separately, can you explain it further for me please?

Comment: Thank you so much , i completely grabbed the concept now.